# disable sort icon in datatable not working for first column

Tags: php, zend-framework, datatable

I'm using `"bSortable": false` and `"orderable": false` but still sort asc icon visible in first column header. I have tried `"bsort":false` and `"orderable": false, "targets": "_all"` but still the icon is visible.

If i use `"aaSorting":[]` this it throws

> Undefined variable: orderColumn

Mycode:

```
var test_table = $('#testDataTable').DataTable({
                // "lengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100,150,200], [10, 50, 100,150,200]],
                "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100], [25, 50, 100]],
                "iDisplayLength": 25,
                "sScrollX" : "100%",
                "scrollX" : true,
                "processing" : true,
                "serverSide" : true,
                "destroy":true,

                "ajax" : { 
                            url: "/test/datatable.php", 
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { status: 'ok' }
                        },
                'columnDefs' : [{"searchable": true, "orderable": false, "targets": '_all' }, {"width": "12%", 'targets': [3,4,5] }]
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

For me this works all the time ;)

```
var test_table = $('#testDataTable').DataTable({
                // "lengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100,150,200], [10, 50, 100,150,200]],
                "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100], [25, 50, 100]],
                "iDisplayLength": 25,
                "sScrollX" : "100%",
                "scrollX" : true,
                "processing" : true,
                "serverSide" : true,
                "destroy":true,

                "ajax" : { 
                            url: "/test/datatable.php", 
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { status: 'ok' }
                        },
                "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ "_all" ] }],
                "aaSorting": []
            });
```